# Управление спикером

Tags: windows, c++

Можно ли как-то вызывать пищание спикера на C++? Обращайтесь со мной как с нубом, пожалуйста. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите функцию BOOL WINAPI Beep. [Beep Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277(VS.85).aspx):

> Выдает простые тона на динамик.